# How can I sort a yaml file by the top level node while excluding certain lines from the sorting?

Tags: sorting, yaml, yq

**What I'm trying to do**

I have a file with one top level parent that I want to remain at the top of the document, and then I have many other parents that I want to sort on a child key. I want to be able to sort only those subsequent parent nodes and leave the specific parent in whatever place in the file it exists in.

**What I'd like to be able to do**

If we have data1.yaml like:

```yaml
---
Australia:
  zoo:
    animals:
      - animal: kangaroos
        population: 3
      - animal: bears
        population: 5
      - animal: aardvark
        population: 3
awsFunctionminimor:
  - name: minimor
awsFunctionfabulous:
  - name: fabulous
awsFunctiondancingpear:
  - name: dancingp
```

And we run a command:

```bash
yq '. |= sort_by(.) && ignorelines=[(1,16)]' data1.yaml
```

it could output

```yaml
---
Australia:
  zoo:
    animals:
      - animal: aardvark
        population: 3
      - animal: bears
        population: 5
      - animal: kangaroos
        population: 3
awsFunctiondancingpear:
  - name: dancingp
awsFunctionfabulous:
  - name: fabulous
awsFunctionminimor:
  - name: minimor
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried running `yq '. |= sort_by(.)' data1.yml` which doesn't work as the node is not an array.

Comment: That's not a valid YAML file.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python] if you don't show any Python code? The [officially recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. Are you going to catch up sometime? As @larsks indicated the (output) document is invalid, you probably want to dedent `awsFunctionminimor`. Your input and ouput are inconsistently indented, I'm not sure `yq` can preserve that.

Comment: Re "I've tried running `… sort_by …` which doesn't work as the node is not an array.": Exactly, `animals` is the only array for which sorting makes sense. The other arrays (`awsFunctiondancingpear`, `awsFunctionfabulous`, and `awsFunctionminimor`) only have one element each, and the rest is objects which do not have a logical order (only one in representation which may be disregarded by any other processor).

Comment: As the arrays only have one element each would the only solution to this be to put them into an array, sort, then extract from that array to put into the final `yaml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the context node, as in `. |= …`, is superfluous; the function provided as the RHS of the update operator is always applied to the current context. Also, using `sort_by(.)` with the context as criteria is the same as just using `sort`.

You want to traverse to the array about to be sorted, here `.Australia.zoo.animals`, then update `|=` that using `sort_by` with providing the sorting criteria as arguments. Here, it appears that you want to sort by the local value of `.animal` only. To introduce secondary criteria (e.g. `.population`, `length`, whatever), just append those values as a stream to the criteria argument (e.g. `sort_by(.animal, .population)`).

This works with [both implementations of yq](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) (tested with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.34.1, and [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) version 2.12.0), please specify which one you're targetting.

```bash
.Australia.zoo.animals |= sort_by(.animal)
```

```yaml
---
Australia:
  zoo:
    animals:
      - animal: aardvark
        population: 3
      - animal: bears
        population: 5
      - animal: kangaroos
        population: 3
awsFunctionminimor:
  - name: minimor
awsFunctionfabulous:
  - name: fabulous
awsFunctiondancingpear:
  - name: dancingp
```

Comment: I've been using the mikefarah/yq implementation. Is there no way to sort the set of `awsFunction_` arrays? That's the part I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @thleo You can sort each of those arrays. But the arrays themselves are not organized in a superordinate array (which would be sortable as well) but in a map (aka object) which by definition has no order. The order you see is merely a representational artifact, and is not part of the logic conveyed by YAML as a data format.

Comment: @thleo That said, you can trick yq into producing your desired output by transforming the outermost map into an array, then sorting it according to some values (the key, or the values below `.name`), and then transforming it back into a map using `to_entries | sort_by(.key) | from_entries` or `to_entries | sort_by(.value[].name) | from_entries`, but keep in mind that this order is just a coincident outcome. Neither yq guarantees that this will still work in a future release, nor would anyone processing this YAML expect that this (or any) map's items bear a significant order.